# How do I prevent Windows 10 removing desktop shortcut parameters?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, desktop

Something(*??*) zapped the parameters on ALL my shortcuts recently.

For example, a shortcut such as:

```
 "%JAVA_HOME%\java" -jar myApp.jar
```

Stopped working, because it had been modified to:

```
 "%JAVA_HOME%\java"
```

No more parameters. :-(  Reconstructing them took quite some time and I'd like to prevent needing to go through that again.

Can you say ...

- What tool / update or whatever may have caused this?
- Offer a method to prevent that happening again?

  - Clearly, I need to ensure my desktop keeps getting backed-up (*too*).
  - I'd prefer at the same time to NOT have to delve into backups if I can prevent the *wipe* in the first instance.
    Many thanks in advance.
  - Finally, do you know of a `tool` that will let me (re-)create shortcuts from CMD file.  May be something like:

  make-shortcut "command line"  "start-location" ["icon-path"]

Hopefully that conveys the idea.

***possibly related***:

- [Preventing Windows from automatically removing broken desktop shortcuts](https://superuser.com/a/467739/133890)

  - However, my shortcuts were never actually broken (that I know of).

Comment: We will be unable to recommend any tool for obvious reasons so you might as well remove that request

Comment: @Ramhound ... not asking for a recommendation, asking about existence of _something_.  I have yet to find anything after exhaustive `google`-ing(tm).

Answer (score 2):

A number of Windows 10 updates have caused different issues with shortcuts, in addition to the one you mentioned:

1. Shortcuts have been restricted to work only in specific folders.
2. Keyboard shortcuts set for .lnk shortcuts may no longer work.

Third-party tools such as [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/classicshell/) allow links to be placed in other folders, or set within the shell environment.

Moving the .lnk files out of the folders managed by Microsoft during Windows updates should, hopefully, protect the links from mangling.

Other tools such as [Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/clavier/) supplement *keyboard* shortcuts. Clavier+, for example, keeps its settings in an .ini file and also enables exporting and importing settings, simplifying repair or setup of a new system. Links (including passed command-line parameters) can be tested as they are entered.

[image: Clavier+ settings dlg]

Comment: Agreed, the comment was removed. However, I've had standard .lnk files, and/or their keyboard shortcuts, become inoperative on two machines after October 2017 updates, so plainly there *is* an issue caused by the updates. That is why I *now* use third-party keyboard shortcut tools.